# getContentResolver in Separate Class

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I need a class to get the artists, albums and tracks on the device, which I will then use JNI to call upon.

At the moment, in its barebones, the following causes a crash.

```
public class AndroidMediaLibray extends Activity {
    public void getArtists() {
        getContentResolver();
    }
}
```

How do I get this to not crash?

Comment: You should post the logcat. Or at least tell us what exception you get.

Comment: 08-17 14:44:58.754  11871-11871/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)

Not sure if that helps. Not used to Java at all.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to call the `getArtist()` from the `onCreate` of the `MainActivity`. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct. I'm guessing this is bad. :P Where should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have, is that you need to call `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`. If you call it in an `Activity`, you automatically call it on the `Context` of the `Activity`. But you (probably) never really start `AndroidMediaLibrary`. Please refer to the [documentation of activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html). If you want to have the DB call in an extra class, you may have a look at the following code. I have created a class with **static** methods. I just need to pass the context of my given `Activity` to that class. In your case that class might look like this:

```
public class AndroidMediaLibrary {

    public static List<String> getArtists(Context context){

        ArrayList<String> retVal = new ArrayList<String>();

        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();        

        // some more stuff here.. 

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

You may call that function from your MainActivity with:

```
List<String> myValues = DBUtils.someFunction(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I didn't use the static implementation, but not sure if that matters. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: It works without a static implementation, too. The problem was, that you were trying to access to `Context` of the `AndroidMediaLibrary` activity that was not available. I think some more basic understanding by reading the documentation would help a lot.

Comment: It might help. I plan on using Qt, and as little Java as possible. I only intend to use it if I need to implement platform specific features.